# Plugging in USB device shorts out USB hub

Tags: power, usb, usb-hub

My device is 12V DC and takes a maximum to 1.08 Amps. The cable is split where one end goes into power and the other end goes into USB.

**Works:**

Plug device power into 120V AC adapter which converts to 12V DC 1.08A.

**Does not work:**

Plug straight into 12V DC

Device powers on in both scenarios because the LED blinks green. One interesting difference is that the LED blink is shorter when connected to straight DC (Battery) Power.

*Note:* The battery is a 11.1V LiPo. I have a DC step-up booster connected which is putting out a steady 12V to my device. I've testing a 12V 5A computer on this same line and it works fine.

## Question

What should I do / check to find out why this is not working?

## EDIT

- Powered USB wire is a split cable - 2 lines in 1 line out

  - Can plug into AC 120V Adapter (works)
  - OR can plug into DC 12V Battery (does not work)
- Device plugs into Powered USB (middle plug)
- Powered USB plugs directly into USB Hub (right plug)

[image]

Comment: **120V** DC? Not 12V?

Comment: Does the ground signal go to the USB port as well as the PSU? A schematic would help clear things up.

Comment: @TomCarpenter I'm not sure how to draw a schematic for this so I took a photo of all the pieces together and added some notes about the photo with hopes to make the situation more clear.

Comment: An 11.1V LiPo will have a fully charged voltage of 12.6V. Do you know for sure if your device (or your boost regulator) is tolerant of this slight overvoltage?

Comment: @LosFrijoles I use a DC step-up booster which keeps the output at a straight 12V DC output. [Here's the exact booster I'm using](https://youtu.be/tKSIAPo5aMk)

Comment: So  standalone battery doesn't work?, is it the first time you configuring it up, could be common ground problem, tried changing hubs?

Comment: @MaMba the same hub works when connected to the AC adapter, just not straight DC.

Comment: I bypassed the 12V DC/DC booster/transformer and went straight to the battery. This works. Any idea what that means?

Comment: @Jacksonkr - I've written an answer to explain what I think is happening, but unless you have access to an oscilloscope, I don't see any way to *prove* the cause, only to infer it from test results. One other thing - I don't understand what you meant by your title of "[...] shorts out USB hub". I saw no indication of any short-circuit in your description - only that the Kinect didn't work when powered via the boost converter. Did you really mean that there was a short-circuit and, if so, how did you diagnose that? Or did you just mean that the USB hub didn't work? Or something else?

Comment: @SamGibson I cannot tell you how much I appreciate your detailed hypothesis. As you can tell by my rep I'm still new here and I'm sure my literal word choices will become more accurate with time. By "short out" the hub I mean that as soon as I plugged the powered USB cable into the hub, the hub lost power and so did any devices that were connected. I assume this is due do the "dirty power" you speak of in your answer. I have an arduino so do you think a [virtual oscilloscope like this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Oscilloscope-poor-mans-Oscilloscope/) is worth a try?

Comment: @Jacksonkr - Hi, thanks for the info. I don't own a Kinect, so don't know how "dirty" input power might affect its USB behaviour. It would need lots more questions (and perhaps an oscilloscope!) to try to understand more. But EE.SE is not designed for lots of to-and-fro troubleshooting in the comments, which is why I didn't reply to your question earlier - my list of questions was too long! But the bottom line - the hub appearing to "lose power" does not mean there is a short-circuit. I can't find any info on the "virtual oscilloscope" page about accuracy or bandwidth etc so I can't tell [...]

Comment: [...] if it would display enough detail in order to help or not. As with any test, especially with an unknown "tool", if it doesn't show a problem, that does *not* mean a problem doesn't exist. It may just be that the "tool" is too limited to accurately show the problem e.g. ripple/noise. Therefore that "tool" could *not* be used to prove that the output of the boost converter is OK. :-( Of course the boost converter's output might be so bad (ripple/noise etc.), that even that "tool" confirms there *is* a problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I bypassed the 12V DC/DC booster/transformer and went straight to the battery. This works. Any idea what that means?

Yes - I was going to ask you to do that test of powering it direct from the LiPo battery, after I read that the Kinect can use a power supply voltage lower than its nominal 12 V, according to [this webpage](http://www.kinecthesia.com/2011/04/kinect-minimum-voltage.html):

> "We found that at 12V the Kinect operates and draws about 0.35A. We kept decreasing the voltage and we found that the **minimum operating voltage for the Kinect is about 8.5V**. At this level it drew about 0.42A."

The likely cause is because the DC output from cheap boost converters can have lots of ripple at the switching frequency, as well as other potential noise. In other words, although yours *says* 12 V on the built-in LED voltmeter, that does *not* mean that its DC output is as smooth as the real DC from a battery, or even from a good-quality mains power adapter.

Ideally, you would use an oscilloscope to view the output voltage from that boost converter, to confirm ripple / noise on the output as the cause, and that's what I was going to suggest - but I guess that if you had an oscilloscope, you would have used it already.

Another way is to test powering your Kinect using *only* a suitable battery within that input power voltage range of the Kinect mentioned above (e.g. LiPo or lead-acid) - *without* using a boost converter. If the Kinect then works OK, we can *infer* the cause of the problem as being the *quality* of the DC output from your boost converter - and that is what you have done. :-)

Your DC-powered PC (or some other devices) may work OK connected to that boost converter, if they have enough power conditioning on their power inputs to cope with any ripple & noise on the boost converter's output.

Adding extra capacitance or filtering between the output of the boost converter and the power input of your Kinect *might* allow the Kinect to then work, while using that boost converter.  However without an oscilloscope to confirm this hypothesis of the cause, and to help identify what filtering or smoothing is needed, you would be left with trial-and-error about what to try.

Comment: The computer has two usb ports (2.0, 3.0). I had the hub into the 3.0 port with wireless N + kinect. I moved the hub + wireless to the 2.0 hub and left the kinect in the 3.0 port by itself. Now the hub does not lose power. I think using a non-powered USB hub may have been the real issue. Regardless I learned a lot from this answer so I'm leaving it up for any future visitors as it will be beneficial for them as well. Thanks again!